# Using Firebase Authentication from iOS 7.1.2 Safari

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, mobile-safari

I see this error:

> Error: This operation is not supported in the environment this
>   application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or
>   chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

When I use:

```
 firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('popup', error);
            //webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
                .then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('redirect', error);
                    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
                        console.log('anonymous', error);
                    });
                });
        });
```

The first two login attempts via popup and redirect fail.  It seems to happen only on iOS Safari.

I see others reporting the issue with Cordova, but I don't see an answer and I'm only using web and firebase. Not Cordova or ionic etc.

The anonymous login works on iOS but that is only a test and not what we want to use to use.

If you want to test it you can use https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/ from Safari on iOS

An example dump of the error object from the returned Promise is:

> {"code": "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment",
>   "constructor": function (a, b)
>   {this.code="auth/"+a;this.message=b||Xf[a]||"";}, "F": function ()
>   {return{code:this.code,message:this.message}}, "line": 44, "message":
>   "This operation is not supported in the environment this application
>   is running on. \"location.protocol\" must be http, https or
>   chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.", "sourceURL":
>   "[https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/**/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js**](https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js)",
>   "stack":
>   "[https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com//firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:44:638](https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:44:638)\nhttps://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/**/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:45:258\nA@[https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/](https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:44:545)**/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:44:545\nD@[https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/**/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:45:242**](https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:45:242)\nsignInWithPopup@[https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com//firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:241:48](https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:241:48)\na@https://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js:260:432\nhttps://meetup-reporter.firebaseapp.com/scripts/main.js:430:36",
>   "toJSON": function () {var
>   a=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);a:{var
>   e=Array.prototype.slice.call(a);var l=0;for(var
>   n=!1,C=0;Cl||l>=fk.length)throw new N("internal-error","Argument
>   validator received an unsupported number of arguments.");e=fk[l]+"
>   argument "+(e.name?'"'+e.name+'" ':"")+"must be "+e.N+".";break
>   a}e=null}}if(e)throw new N("argument-error",d+" failed: "+e);return
>   b.apply(this,a);}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

signInWithRedirect actually works in Cordova now: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova
signInWithPopup and signInWithRedirect should also work for iOS7 and up. I just tested both on an iOS 7 device and they both work. What you are experiencing is likely to the fact that you are using this operation in Safari Private/Incognito mode where web storage is disabled. These operations depend on web storage in order to securely communicate the OAuth result to the parent page. You will need to ask your users to switch to regular mode when this happens, or you can use the Google Sign-in JS SDk to get the OAuth credential and then signInWithCredential. I think it may work in incognito mode.

Comment: Thanks @bojeil I tested and I could not get mobile safari to work via the firebase signInWithPopup or signInWithRedirect.  But the google sign-in JS SDK does work with older iphones/safari/etc, Thanks!  For those that want to do that see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-handle-the-sign-in-flow-manually